# How to calculate this average value in Impala

Tags: sql, impala

i have a table in Impala which look like this:

```
product..Pgroup...testtype...result 
....A.... 1.....length......2.0mm
....B.....1.....length......4.0mm
....C.....1.....weight......3.0gr
....D.....1.....weight......1.0gr
....E.....2.....weight......2.0gr
....F.....2.....weight......2.0gr
```

i want to canculate average value pro each testtype and group by Pgroup. the result i would like to have looks like this:

```
Pgroup....testtype...averageresult
1.........length.....3.0mm
1.........weigth.....2.0gr
2.........weigth.....2.0gr
```

Can you please help?

```
create table test_1 (product string, pgroup string, testtype string, result string);
insert into test_1 values ('A', '1', 'length','2.0mm'),
('B', '1', 'length','4.0mm'),
('C', '1', 'weight','3.0gr'),
('D', '1', 'weight','1.0gr'),
('E', '2', 'weight','2.0gr'),
('F', '2', 'weight','2.0gr')
```

Comment: You cannot take the average of a string.  I would suggest storing the data in a more reasonable format, such as a scalar (numeric) measurement along with a separate column for the units.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky solution would be

```
select pgroup, testtype, concat(cast(avg(cast(regexp_extract(result,'[0-9\.]+', 0) as double)) as string), 
                                case testtype when 'length' then 'mm' when 'weight' then 'gr' end) 
from test_1 group by pgroup, testtype;
```

Though I definitely recommend to create a preprocessed table with value and unit splitted into two columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest below

```
SELECT pgroup, testtype
    , CONCAT(AVG( CAST( SUBSTRING( result, 1, LENGTH(result)-2) AS DOUBLE)),
        CASE testtype WHEN 'length' THEN 'mm' WHEN 'weight' THEN 'gr' END)
FROM test_1 
GROUP BY pgroup, testtype;
```

and as others suggested the better approach would be create a separate columns for result and measurement.